# How to create a string message in a ROS package with catkin correctly?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the output of `catkin_make` that shows an error.

```
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
        Base path: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws
        Source space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/src
        Build space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build
        Devel space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/devel
        Install space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/install
        ####
        #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build"
        ####
        -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/devel
        -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
        -- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
        -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
        -- Using Debian Python package layout
        -- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
        -- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
        -- Call enable_testing()
        -- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/notsotechni
        cal/catkin_ws/build/test_results
        -- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
        -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
        -- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
        -- catkin 0.7.17
        -- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
        -- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
        -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        -- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
        -- ~~  - repo_name_hw2
        -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        -- +++ processing catkin package: 'repo_name_hw2'
        -- ==> add_subdirectory(repo_name_hw2)
        -- Could NOT find roscpp (missing: roscpp_DIR)
        -- Could not find the required component 'roscpp'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
        CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
          Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
          of the following names:
        
            roscppConfig.cmake
            roscpp-config.cmake
        
          Add the installation prefix of "roscpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
          "roscpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "roscpp"
          provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
          installed.
        Call Stack (most recent call first):
          repo_name_hw2/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
        
        
        -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
        See also "/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
        See also "/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
        Makefile:334: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
        make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
        Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
        notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$
```

I also tried the following:

```
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/notsotechnical/Programs
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/home/notsotechnical/Programs
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$
```

---

Update

Hey I got rid of thw following errors by reinstalling ROS melodic:

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
of the following names:

```
        roscppConfig.cmake
        roscpp-config.cmake
```

However, I got more errors :(

```
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.17
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - repo_name_hw2
-- ~~  - repo_uniquename_hw2
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'repo_name_hw2'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(repo_name_hw2)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- repo_name_hw2: 1 messages, 0 services
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:196 (message):
  catkin_package() the catkin package 'roscpp' has been find_package()-ed but
  is not listed as a build dependency in the package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  repo_name_hw2/CMakeLists.txt:106 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:334: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333844/how-to-create-a-string-message-in-a-ros-package-with-catkin-correctly?/) by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-24**:
We're going to need some more information here. Can you show us your code (source, CMakeLists.txt, etc.) in addition to this output?

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-24**:
CMakerlist:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ws3hZ5CyU9cVsz2zhTf7PlP2VJI3wXC_/view?usp=sharing

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-24**:
I also tried the following:
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/notsotechnical/Programs
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/home/notsotechnical/Programs
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~$

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-24**:
Can you please update your question with the contents of the file instead of linking to it? That keeps the question self-contained (and useful to others in the future) if/when that link no longer works

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2019-09-24**:
It would also help to know what you have in `package.xml`, since it appears that your package is not able to find `roscpp` package. It is in `CMakeLists.txt`. If it is not declared as a dependency in `package.xml` that could explain the error.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2019-09-24**:
When pasting code/files please remove the commented out boilerplate. Having a minimal working example makes it easier to see what is going on.

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-24**:
I'm not sure why, but it says "This content is forbidden" whenever I paste something that is long in the comment.  package.xml: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k2Wnbu2nYjr06JW-gv-yCgFfDTBHOGTt/view?usp=sharing

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-24**:
@notSoTechnical That's because comments aren't for code, files, etc., they're for shorter exchanges. Codes, files, etc. should be put in questions as an update.

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-24**:
@jayess Thx!  I'm new

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-24**:
No problem, welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have two options:

- Add the following line to `package.xml`:

```
<depend>roscpp</depend>
```

- According to your `CMakeLists.txt` you are not building a library or executable, only messages. Therefore, you could remove `roscpp` from your `CMakeLists.txt` file. You could also remove the `include_directories()` line from `CMakeLists.txt` for now.

If you were to add code into the `repo_name_hw2` package, you would need to go with Option 1. If you are only going to have messages/services/actions defined in the `repo_name_hw2` package you would probably want to go with Option 2.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-24**:
Hey Tom!  Thanks!  I deleted roscpp and it seemed working... until I can't display the message.  Any idea? https://answers.ros.org/question/333876/how-to-display-the-ros-message-in-the-terminal/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-25**:
@notSoTechnical: the enthusiasm is appreciated, but could you please follow up on your open questions first? Right now you have a flurry of questions open, with no clear resolution, and you jumping to different subjects in the comments beneath the potential answers.

I'd recommend to be a little more methodical in troubleshooting and when interacting with forum members here.

**Comment by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on 2019-09-25**:
@gvdhoorn   Sorry, I'm new.  I will be more methodical in the future

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-25**:
No need to apologise. Just keep it in mind.